# Store XAML to DB

Tags: sql, database, xaml, workflow

I'm working on designing a workflow and the output is a XAML file, I need to store that file in SQL DataBase .. How can I do that? What do you think is the suitable extension to convert to?

Answer (score 0):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/11/19/windows-workflow-foundation-4-and-persistence.aspx).

**PRO TIP** - Google is a search engine. You can use search engines to find things.

Comment: Perhaps a real pro would rather point out that the essence of an SQL database is not the extension of its files ...